# Replacing the source attribute of multiple JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get it when a button is clicked, all buttons are given the Off state, (src is btnCircuitxOff.gif) and the one selected is given the On state (src is btnCircuitxOn)

That is clicking one will deselect the others and select itself, this is only visual feedback for a physical device on the other end of an ajax query, otherwise I would use radio buttons themselves.

So far I have,

Html / css

```
<div id='controls'>
<input type="image" class = "Circuit _100" src="btnCircuit100Off.gif" onclick="selectCircuit('100');"/>
<input type="image" class = "Circuit _10K" src="btnCircuit10KOff.gif" onclick="selectCircuit('10K');"/>
<input type="image" class = "Circuit _100K" src="btnCircuit100KOff.gif" onclick="selectCircuit('100K');"/>
<input type="image" class = "Circuit _1M" src="btnCircuit1MOff.gif" onclick="selectCircuit('1M');"/>
<input type="image" class = "Circuit _10M" src="btnCircuit10MOff.gif" onclick="selectCircuit('10M');"/>
<input type="image" class = "reset" src="btnReset.gif" onclick="reset();"/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function selectCircuitButtons(s) 
{
  $(".Circuit").attr("src",$(".Circuit").attr("src").replace("On","Off"));
  $("._"+s).attr("src",$("._"+s).attr("src").replace("Off","On"));  
}
```

Which almost seems to work, except that as soon as I click something, every image gets replaced with btnCircuit100Off instead of their individual btnCircuitxOff images.

I'm almost sure I almost have a solution, but how can I store each selector to use when editing the src element?

I've looked at .each and $(this) but I'm new to JQuery and am having troubles formulating a solution.

Also suggestions for a good title are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the current value of the attribute for each element, rather than always reading a single value.

To help you with that, jQuery allows you to pass a callback:

```
$(".Circuit").attr("src",
    function(elem, oldSrc) { return oldSrc.replace("On","Off"); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.each to iterate through each matching item

```
function selectCircuitButtons(s) {
    $(".Circuit, ._"+s).each(function(index,item){
        $(item).attr("src",$(item).attr("src").replace("On","Off"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to iterate through circuite using `$.each`
2. You have to toggle each image name along element has class or not:

   ```
   function selectCircuitButtons(s) {

       $(".Circuit").each(function() {
            var hasS = $(this).hasClass("_"+ s);
            if(hasS) {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("Off","On"));
            } else {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("On","Off"));
            }
       });
   }
   ```

**EDIT simpler (with @SLaks technique):**

```
function selectCircuitButtons(s) {

    $(".Circuit").attr("src", function(elem, oldSrc) {
        return $(elem).hasClass("_"+ s) ?
            oldSrc.replace("Off","On") : oldSrc.replace("On","Off");
    });
}
```